# What to do about cold spots on new electric heated floor?

Tags: contractors, remodel

I just had a new remodel done which included electric in floor heating. During the install they set the wires with leveler which ultimately sealed them in place.

They sent me photos of the progress done because I had asked that they keep me in the loop before they do anything irreversible. Well, they did it anyway and sent me photos after. In the photos I identified a very large gap between the cable runs in a very high traffic spot. I brought this to their attention and said it’s clear that spot will be noticeably cooler than the surrounding. They disagreed and said it’s fine.

I emailed back and forth on this so have a record of our discussion and stated that I’m concerned if there are cold spots they’re going to have to do whatever it takes to make it correct.

Lo and behold, the heated floor has a noticeable cold spot in the worst possible spot —center of the floor and in front of the vanity.

I’m not sure how to really approach telling them they need to rip out basically the entire bathroom and floors , and start over ..because there’s nothing else I can think of to fix this issue.

Anyone have any advice on how to broach this subject with them?  I don’t want to fight about it but the fact is I paid a lot for them to do the job right. And they did it wrong. And I even pointed that out when there was time to fix it before it got too messy. And they didn’t. And now we are where we are —and I’m just kind of at a loss for how to politely inform them of this extremely expensive(for them) and time wasting mistake.

Comment: Have you paid them already?

Comment: @popham I’ve been paying as the remodel progresses. But there’s still roughly 40% of the remaining balance due once they do the final walk. Of course the contractor was quick to tell me they’re ending the next invoice asap …but I won’t pay it until we discuss this issue.

Comment: rent a thermal camera to get proof of the cold spot, that will help your negotiations regarding this

Comment: Is there accessible space underneath?

Comment: This is a legal/contractual issue and off topic here. Try https://law.stackexchange.com. Good luck--that's an unfortunate situation.

Comment: Or, it could be good for [ips.se], since the question is how to broach the subject.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because resolving contract issues does not fall within the purview of [diy.se].

Answer (score 7):

Express your concerns diplomatically about the cold spot, referencing documented communication highlighting the issue beforehand. Stress the expectation for a resolution given the significant investment and request a site visit to assess and discuss corrective measures.

Comment: I'd also consider getting infrared imagery of the area. That'll put to rest any dispute over performance.